# Translate Content in JavaScript an HTML with the Google Translate API

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I need to create a button that will be able to toggle the language of a page's content between French and English.

How can I use the Google Translate API for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this help :

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    // here is where you change the language
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

[Source](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools)

Comment: I am using google translate on https. So i am using `https://stgstatdt.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/transliteration.I.js` this file. I want toggle language from one to other and vice versa in button click... Please help