# Google Translate API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-translate

I have this fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/gsrgfd8e/

```
$(".word_split").lettering('words');
```

I want every word to display a google translation on mouseover. 
The documentation doesn't specify a way to do that in Javascript. Apparently I could do that with node.js but I'm not sure how.

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: There are several ways to go at it.  You may want to have the translations ready before the user even starts highlighting.  This way you can store all translations on a client object or array.  and just display that.  Otherwise, you'll have to hit the google translate API every single time the user hovers over any word.  How do you plan on accessing the API?

Answer (score 0):

For the JavaScript part of the solution, you can check the reply to the "[Html text hover over each word for translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132108/html-text-hover-over-each-word-for-translation)" question.

On how to call the Translate API, you have an example in "[Translate Content in JavaScript an HTML with the Google Translate API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426017/translate-content-in-javascript-an-html-with-the-google-translate-api)".